# Deleting relation data with one of the composite keys spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have relation Entity with composite primary key.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@IdClass(VulnerabilityTargetId.class)
@Table(name = "vulnerabilities_targets")
@Where(clause = "deleted='false'")
@SQLDelete(
    sql =
        "UPDATE vulnerabilities_targets SET deleted = true WHERE target_id = ? and vulnerability_id = ?")
public class VulnerabilityTarget extends BaseRelEntity {

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "target_id")
  private Target target;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "vulnerability_id")
  private Vulnerability vulnerability;


  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    VulnerabilityTarget that = (VulnerabilityTarget) o;
    return target.equals(that.target) && vulnerability.equals(that.vulnerability);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(target, vulnerability);
  }
}
```

And also **Vulnerability** and **Target** entities. And my Id class is :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class VulnerabilityTargetId implements Serializable {

  private long vulnerability;
  private long target;

}
```

BTW i tried to add target id to **VulnerabilityTarget** entity like this and got error 'Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.security.raze.pojo.internal.entity.relation.VulnerabilityTarget_AUD'

```
@Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "target_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Target target;

@Column(name = "target_id")
private Long targetId;
```

So, i want to delete all relations when i deleting a target. How can i delete **VulnerabilityTarget** by using target_id? (Via named query or by using cascase remove)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches on web i find a solution to perform delete operation on a relation table with composite id and i am adding as a solution. But i think a concise way more than my solution could possibly exist.

```
@Repository
public interface VulnerabilityTargetRepository
    extends JpaRepository<VulnerabilityTarget, VulnerabilityTargetId> {
  @Transactional
  @Modifying
  @Query(
      value =
          "UPDATE VulnerabilityTarget vt SET vt.deleted = true WHERE vt.target IN (Select t from Target t WHERE t.id = :targetId)")
  void deleteByTargetId(long targetId);
}
```

NOTE : some parts of the question needs to be clarified this answer only makes clear how wwe can delete relational entity has composite PK.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a targetId basic mapping as well as a target reference mapping, try using derived ids:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@IdClass(VulnerabilityTargetId.class)
@Table(name = "vulnerabilities_targets")
@Where(clause = "deleted='false'")
@SQLDelete(
    sql =
        "UPDATE VulnerabilityTarget SET deleted = true WHERE targetId = ? and vulnerabilityId = ?")
public class VulnerabilityTarget extends BaseRelEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "vulnerability_id")
  private Long vulnerabilityId;

  @MapsId("vulnerabilityId")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Vulnerability vulnerability;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "target_id")
  private Long targetId;

  @MapsId("targetId")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Target target;
}
```

You just then need to change the VulnerabilityTargetId to rename the target and vulnerability properties to targetId and vulnerabilityId respectively.

Comment: if i use @MapsId, do i have to implement cascade operations and orphan removal feature  manually right? If i have to this will not be a concise way.

Comment: my vulnerability is related with this relation entity like this : @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vulnerability", orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<VulnerabilityTarget> vulnerabilityTargets = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: BTW after apply this solution an error thrown because of hibernate envers. Error is : Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.security.raze.pojo.internal.entity.relation.VulnerabilityTarget_AUD column: target_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: @Id
  @Column(name = "target_id")
  private Long targetId;

  @MapsId("targetId")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Target target;

i am using 'insertable = false, updatable = false' but it does not changed

Comment: MapsId is a separate annotation so doesn’t change other ManyToOne operations such as cascade options like cascade delete. If you set them, they will work the same. Orphan removal doesn’t make sense though in any case, as the relation is ties to the id, and the id cannot change in JPA entities. For you last comment- why are you adding the join column? Remove it. The point of mapsid is that it uses the same dB column for both a basic and relational mapping, setting both from the value in the reference

Comment: When i removed @JoinColumn(name = "target_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) I am getting same error

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.security.raze.pojo.internal.entity.relation.VulnerabilityUser_AUD column: vulnerability_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: when i make relation not audited like below exception is no be thrown.
@NotAudited
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vulnerability", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<VulnerabilityTarget> vulnerabilityTargets = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Auditing is a separate feature outside of JPA- and explains the _AUD postfix in the error. Hibernate auditing must not have support for mapsId, and is picking it up as two separate columns to audit - which means you must add the @NotAudited annotation or some indicator to help it out and tell it how to handle it on one of the two mappings.

Comment: i guess this is a bug about hibernate envers.